# Making Images hidden next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image scroller and I am stuck with my CSS side of things. The current CSS that I have is making them going under each other not next to each other and I can't figure out how to make it work that way.

The Images are stored in a div of themselves which are under a another div called imageScroller and the imageScroller div is under the Content div.

Here is the CSS of the following divs

```
#content
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
#imageScroller{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 850px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: the number of images exceeds the available width of `#imageScroller` element?

Comment: Yes they take all of the width of the ImageScoller div.

Comment: then you should show us a minimal example on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is achieved by adding `white-space: nowrap` to `#imageSlider` and changing `.image` so that instead of `float: left`, it is `display: inline-block`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6tmvfr0/). Adjust as needed.

The `font-size: 0` in `#imageSlider` is to get rid of extra white space in between the `<div>`s.